# Numbered list of images and code using reStructeredText

Tags: python, restructuredtext

In reStructuredText, how can one achieve a numbered list of elements with non trivial entries?

Example:

```
1. foo
2. bar
   *code block*
3. waldo
   *image*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you **indent** the blocks inside the list items properly, and that you prepend and follow them with a **blank line**.

For example, this...

```
1. This is the first item
2. Enumerators are arabic numbers,
   single letters, or roman numerals

   block::

       pass
       print foo

3. List items should be sequentially
   numbered, but need not start at 1
   (although not all formatters will
   honour the first index).

   .. image:: http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.png
      :height: 49 px
      :width: 526 px

#. This item is auto-enumerated
```

...should render like this:

[image]